# issues in image uploading with php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have some problem in image uploading with php codeigniter.

this is my controller

```
 public function FunctionName()
  {

        $profile_pic  = $this->input->post('profile_pic');
        echo $profile_pic;         

  }
```

It is a simple function and I just want to see the name of the file (image) which I select.

this is my view

```
<form class="" method="post" action="<?=base_url();?>Controller/FunctionName" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="profile_pic">

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>
```

When I run this script. It shows me a blank page. I cannot get/display the name of the file which I selected. Note that I have auto-loaded the helper. E.g.

> $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'date', 'form');

Comment: use echo $_FILES['profile_pic'][name];

Comment: It gives me error: Message: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'

Comment: mine mistake try this . use echo $_FILES['profile_pic'];

Comment: Now It display the string 'Array' instead of the file name, and it also gives error: Message: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file=$_FILES['file_name']['name'];
$config =         array('file_name'=>$file,
                        'upload_path' => "./folder/",
                        'allowed_types' => "jpg|jpeg|png",
                        'remove_spaces' => FALSE,
                        'overwrite' => TRUE
                                        );

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->do_upload('file_name');
```

Comment: It works. thanks alot. I want your further help plz. Now I want to change the original file name to another name, like 'myname_2016' and want to store this new name in database..help me plz.

Comment: just use array('file_name'=>'myname_2016')

Comment: can I store that in an external variable (outside array) so that I can sent it to the database for insertion???

Comment: you can store it an external variable

Comment: Yes got it. This what I did. $varname = $config['file_name'];

Comment: $varname = $config['file_name'] only stores the file name in database without extention. I want to store it with extension like myfile.jpg. How can I do it? plz help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116468/discussion-between-ajmal-razeel-and-reji-kumar).